# KeyError when there exists a key

Tags: python, sqlite, twitter, tweepy

Using Tweepy, I was trying to live stream the Tweets and save it into database sqlite but as soon as I load the JSON file and store into database the error keeps on occurring saying `KeyError : created_at` but there already exists a key `created_at`. I tried with others too, but still the error persists.

Here is my code:

```
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect("twitter.db")
import sys
import tweepy
import json
tb_create = "CREATE TABLE tweets2(created_at, favorite_count, favorited, filter_level, lang, retweet_count, retweeted, source, text, truncated, user_created_at, user_followers_count, user_location, user_lang, user_name, user_screen_name, user_time_zone, user_utc_offset, user_friends_count)"
c = conn.cursor()
c.execute(tb_create)
conn.commit

import tweepy

class MaxListener(tweepy.StreamListener):
  def on_data(self, raw_data):
    all_data = json.loads(raw_data)

    created_at = all_data['created_at']
    favorite_count = all_data["favorite_count"]
    favorited = all_data["favorited"]
    filter_level = all_data["filter_level"]
    lang = all_data["lang"]
    retweet_count = all_data["retweet_count"]
    retweeted = all_data["retweeted"]
    source = all_data["source"]
    text = all_data["text"]
    truncated = all_data["truncated"]
    user_created_at = all_data["user"]["created_at"]
    user_followers_count = all_data["user"]["followers_count"]
    user_location = all_data["user"]["location"]
    user_lang = all_data["user"]["lang"]
    user_name = all_data["user"]["name"]
    user_screen_name = all_data["user"]["screen_name"]
    user_time_zone = all_data["user"]["time_zone"]
    user_utc_offset = all_data["user"]["utc_offset"]
    user_friends_count = all_data["user"]["friends_count"]

    c.execute("INSERT INTO tweets2(created_at, favorite_count, favorited, filter_level, lang, retweet_count, retweeted, source, text, truncated, user_created_at, user_followers_count, user_location, user_lang, user_name, user_screen_name, user_time_zone, user_utc_offset, user_friends_count) VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", (created_at, favorite_count, favorited, filter_level, lang, retweet_count, retweeted, source, text, truncated, user_created_at, user_followers_count, user_location, user_lang, user_name, user_screen_name, user_time_zone, user_utc_offset, user_friends_count))

    conn.commit()

  def process_data(delf,raw_data):
    print(raw_data)

  def on_error(self, status_code):
    if status_code == 420:
      return False

class MaxStream():
  def __init__(self, auth, listner):
    self.stream = tweepy.Stream(auth=auth, listener=listener)

  def start(self, keyword_list):
    self.stream.filter(track= keyword_list)

if __name__ == "__main__":
  listener = MaxListener()
  from tweepy import OAuthHandler
  auth = OAuthHandler(ckey, csecret)
  auth.set_access_token(atoken, asecret)

  stream = MaxStream(auth, listener)
  stream.start("python")
```

**error**

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-0bf7c95f9c6c> in <module>()
     55 
     56   stream = MaxStream(auth, listener)
---> 57   stream.start("python")

8 frames
<ipython-input-4-0bf7c95f9c6c> in on_data(self, raw_data)
     10     all_data = json.loads(raw_data)
     11 
---> 12     created_at = all_data['created_at']
     13     favorite_count = all_data["favorite_count"]
     14     favorited = all_data["favorited"]

KeyError: 'created_at'
```

Comment: Based on this info I don't think there's not much we can tell you beyond what the error says: `'created_at'` doesn't exist in `all_data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`on_data` receives all data from the stream, including [message types](https://developer.twitter.com/en/docs/twitter-api/v1/tweets/filter-realtime/guides/streaming-message-types) that aren't Tweet payloads.

The `KeyError` is almost certainly occurring when one of those other message types is received.

You should check for the existence of an attribute specific to Tweets before using it as a Tweet or consider using `on_status` instead.